# Strange behaviour in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, boolean, expression

If I execute the test function in the following code fragment:

```
function pointInside( r, p ) {
    var result =
        ( p.x >= r.location.x - r.size.width * 0.5 ) &&
        ( p.x <= r.location.x + r.size.width * 0.5 ) &&
        ( p.y >= r.location.y - r.size.height * 0.5 ) &&
        ( p.y <= r.location.y + r.size.height * 0.5 )
    ;
    return result;
}

function test() {
    var rect = {};
    rect["location"] = { x:6, y:5 };
    rect["size"] = { width:10, height:8 };
    var p = { x:10, y:8 };
    var inside = pointInside( rect, p );
    console.log( inside ? "inside" : "outside" );
}
```

then the text "inside" gets written to the console. Great. Now, if I change the pointInside function to this:

```
function pointInside( r, p ) {
    return
        ( p.x >= r.location.x - r.size.width * 0.5 ) &&
        ( p.x <= r.location.x + r.size.width * 0.5 ) &&
        ( p.y >= r.location.y - r.size.height * 0.5 ) &&
        ( p.y <= r.location.y + r.size.height * 0.5 )
    ;
}
```

then when I call the test function "outside" gets written to the console. On further investigation I find that the pointInside function is actually returning undefined. Why? I can't see any meaningful difference between the two versions of pointInside. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately many javascript interpreters try to be forgiving about missing semicolons.  If you have "return" and then an end of line, many interpreters will assume that you have forgotten a semicolon.  Hence your "undefined".

Comment: Whilst I don't agree with a lot of the details, the general feeling is about accurate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5xh0ZIEUOE

Comment: This is part of the spec, it's not something that "many interpreters try to do", it's something that *all* interpreters *must* do.

Comment: Perhaps they must, but as is often the case reality and standards don't always intersect.  I'm using tiny-js at the moment, an embedded interpreter for microcontrollers.  There return waits for a semicolon, so it's not standards compliant in that respect.  Not dealing with weird rules might not be compliant but it keeps the code small and easy to validate for security issues.

Answer (score 11):

In javascript, `;` is optional (at end of statement) ... so your function returns 'undefined' (which is false-y) and the rest of the code in that function is effectively ignored ... wonderful isn't it!!

try the following

```
function pointInside( r, p ) {
    return (
        ( p.x >= r.location.x - r.size.width * 0.5 ) &&
        ( p.x <= r.location.x + r.size.width * 0.5 ) &&
        ( p.y >= r.location.y - r.size.height * 0.5 ) &&
        ( p.y <= r.location.y + r.size.height * 0.5 )
    );
}
```

it's something that will probably never be fixed, this stupid behaviour, because it would break too much (poor) code